# How to visualize experimental data for a single independent variable that depends on 5 discrete variables?

Tags: visualization, graphing, experimental-design

I'm trying to visualize the efficiency of a coaxial UAV propeller test stand with variable coaxial spacing, variable pitch, and variable motor speed. My independent variables are coaxial separation, front motor speed, back motor speed, front motor pitch, and back motor pitch.

My first attempt was to use a web plot. But I feel like it's a bit messy and hard to grab information from. I could lower the dimension and create multiple plots, but if there was a way to describe it all in one, that would be great.

[Rough draft of spider plot showing top 5 efficient configurations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Iwe.png)